# pass array from servlet to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, servlets, aem

## this is my servlet where i am getting sorted array as response

```
    String[] myarray = new String[] {nameOne, nameTwo, nameThree, nameFour, nameFive};
 
    Arrays.sort(myarray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Gson gson=new Gson();
String jsonData=gson.toJson(myarray);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jsonData);
```

below is my javascript code to get array elements as ordered list, my pronblem is i dont know how to access the array from servlet in this javascript.anyone pls explain how can i store the array in a variable (var str)

```
    var str=// i want to store the array from servlet in this variable
    var list = document.createElement("ol");
for (let i of str) {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerHTML = i;
  list.appendChild(item);
}

document.getElementById("demoA").appendChild(list);
```

```
this is html code
<div id="demoA"></div>

I tried request dispatcher but it is useful for jsp files . if solution is to use req dispatcher then pls tell me jsp code to generate that array elementrs as ordered list in html.
```

Comment: Javascript can use XMLHttpRequest to request array from Servlet.

Comment: could you explain me bit in detail

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript/4033310#4033310